# Is there a way to collapse rows based on multiple column conditions, grouped by ID in R?

Tags: r, group-by

I have a df of episodic antibiotic data (long form). For each patient, I’m looking to combine specific antibiotics into “combo” therapies based on 1) a specific list of antibiotics that would be of interest, and 2) ONLY if those specific antibiotics had the same start dates. The specific therapies of interest are:

- Ampicillin and ceftriaxone
- Ampicillin and gentamicin
- Ampicillin and streptomycin

I don’t need any other combinations (e.g. if ampicillin and daptomycin start on the same day, I don’t want that combined).

I have a patient ID by which the antibiotic episodes can be grouped. My start_date variable has already been coerced into date class (YYYY-MM-DD). All other variables are character.

Here’s a sample set of data. In my actual dataframe, have over 1,000 rows.

```
ID <- c("C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C4", "C4", "C5", "C5", "C5", "C6", "C6")

abx <- c("ampicillin", "ceftriaxone", "vancomycin", "linezolid", "ampicillin", "gentamicin", "vancomycin", "piptazo", "daptomycin", "ampicillin", "streptomycin", "vancomycin", "ampicillin", "daptomycin") 

date <- c(as.Date("2020-02-01"), as.Date("2020-02-01"), as.Date("2020-01-28"), as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2020-02-17"), as.Date("2020-02-17"), as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2020-01-11"), as.Date("2020-01-05"), as.Date("2020-01-05"), as.Date("2020-01-05"), as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-14"), as.Date("2020-01-14"))

df_abx <- data.frame(ID, abx, date)
```

This is the solution I’m hoping for:

| ID | abx | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | ampicillin, ceftriaxone | 2020-02-01 |
| C1 | vancomycin | 2020-01-28 |
| C2 | linezolid | 2020-03-01 |
| C3 | ampicillin, gentamicin | 2020-02-17 |
| C3 | vancomycin | 2020-03-01 |
| C4 | piptazo | 2020-01-11 |
| C4 | daptomycin | 2020-01-05 |
| C5 | ampicillin, streptomycin | 2020-01-05 |
| C5 | vancomycin | 2020-01-01 |
| C6 | ampicillin | 2020-01-14 |
| C6 | daptomycin | 2020-01-14 |

I suspect the solution includes "group_by" for the patient ID, and I've been toying around with summarize and case_when but I haven't gotten to where I want to be.

Comment: If 'cef..', 'gen..' and 'strep..' only are combined with ampillicin, then `library(data.table)`; `setDT(df_abx)[ , toString(abx), by = .(g = abx %in% c("ampicillin", "ceftriaxone", "gentamicin", "streptomycin"), ID, date)]`...works for the example provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may group by 'ID', 'date', create a new grouping column with `case_match` by making a common group for the selected drugs, and then add the grouping, to summarise the 'abx' by `paste`ing (`str_c`) the values in `abx`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_abx %>% 
 group_by(ID, date) %>%
  mutate(abx_grp = coalesce(case_match(abx,
   c('ampicillin', 'ceftriaxone', 'gentamicin', 'streptomycin') ~ 'g1'), abx)) %>%
  group_by(abx_grp, .add = TRUE) %>% 
 summarise(abx = str_c(abx, collapse = ", "), .groups = 'drop')  %>% 
 select(-abx_grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 × 3
   ID    date       abx                     
   <chr> <date>     <chr>                   
 1 C1    2020-01-28 vancomycin              
 2 C1    2020-02-01 ampicillin, ceftriaxone 
 3 C2    2020-03-01 linezolid               
 4 C3    2020-02-17 ampicillin, gentamicin  
 5 C3    2020-03-01 vancomycin              
 6 C4    2020-01-05 daptomycin              
 7 C4    2020-01-11 piptazo                 
 8 C5    2020-01-01 vancomycin              
 9 C5    2020-01-05 ampicillin, streptomycin
10 C6    2020-01-14 daptomycin              
11 C6    2020-01-14 ampicillin
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update: the correct version ** We can do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_abx %>% 
  group_by(ID, date) %>% 
  mutate(abx = toString(abx)) %>% 
  anti_join(df1, by="abx") %>% 
  separate_rows(abx) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  bind_rows(df_abx %>%  
              group_by(ID, date) %>%
              mutate(x = ifelse(str_detect(abx, pattern), 1, 0)) %>% 
              filter(sum(x)>=2) %>% 
              summarise(abx= toString(abx))) %>% 
  arrange(ID, abx)
```

```
 ID    abx                      date      
   <chr> <chr>                    <date>    
 1 C1    ampicillin, ceftriaxone  2020-02-01
 2 C1    vancomycin               2020-01-28
 3 C2    linezolid                2020-03-01
 4 C3    ampicillin, gentamicin   2020-02-17
 5 C3    vancomycin               2020-03-01
 6 C4    daptomycin               2020-01-05
 7 C4    piptazo                  2020-01-11
 8 C5    ampicillin, streptomycin 2020-01-05
 9 C5    vancomycin               2020-01-01
10 C6    ampicillin               2020-01-14
11 C6    daptomycin               2020-01-14
```