# Collapsing rows based on date column conditions while still keeping ancillary columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I had a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75496297/is-there-a-way-to-collapse-rows-based-on-multiple-column-conditions-grouped-by) where the feedback was helpful, but now I’m wading into data that’s a little more complicated and I’m hoping someone can iterate for me.

I have episodic antibiotic data in long form, grouped by patient ID. I have already found “combination therapies” where the dates for antibiotic start/stop time and duration line up perfectly. However, now I need to account for combination therapies where the dates may not be perfectly aligned, but there’s generally a pattern (i.e. there’s a “backbone” antibiotic that will always start first, and then a set of antibiotics that can follow which would form a synergistic combination). An example would be:

Ampicillin is the backbone antibiotic. If ceftriaxone, gentamicin or streptomycin start within 3 days of the ampicillin starting, it’s still considered a combination therapy.

What I would like to do is check each patient that has received ampicillin for the other possible “supporting” drugs, and if those drugs start dates are within 1-3 days of the ampicillin start date, I want to change the value in the abx column from “ampicillin” to “ampicillin, ceftriaxone” (or something that simply indicates the combination, doesn’t have to be a comma), maintain the rest of the data in the columns for the ampicillin row (I have additional dates/data that are necessary for later analysis) and deletes the ceftriaxone row and its affiliated data entirely.

Here’s a sample set of my data:

```
ID <- c(‘C1’, ‘C1’, ‘C2’, ‘C2’, ‘C2’, ‘C3’, ‘C4’, ‘C4’, ‘C5’, ‘C5’, ‘C6’)

abx <- c(‘amp’, ‘ceft’, ‘amp’, ‘ceft’, ‘vanc’, ‘amp’, ‘amp’, ‘gent’, ‘amp’, ‘vanc’, ‘vanc’)

abx_start <- c(as.Date(‘1/1/2023’), as.Date(‘1/3/2023’), as.Date(‘1/10/2023’), as.Date(‘1/15/2023’), as.Date(‘1/1/2023’), as.Date(‘1/11/2023’), as.Date(‘1/20/2023’), as.Date(‘1/21/2023’), as.Date(‘1/12/2023’), as.Date(‘1/15/2023’), as.Date(‘1/1/2023’))

abx_stop <- c(as.Date(‘1/30/2023’), as.Date(‘1/29/2023’), as.Date(‘2/14/2023’), as.Date(‘2/14/2023’),as.Date(‘1/3/2023’), as.Date(‘1/24/2023’), as.Date(‘2/10/2023’), as.Date(‘2/08/2023’), as.Date(‘1/30/2023’), as.Date(‘1/15/2023’), as.Date(‘1/14/2023’)) 

cx_final <- c(as.Date(‘1/2/2023’), as.Date(‘1/2/2023’), as.Date(‘1/10/2023’), as.Date(‘1/10/2023’), as.Date(‘1/3/2023’), as.Date(‘1/11/2023’), as.Date(‘1/18/2023’), as.Date(‘1/18/2023’), as.Date(‘1/11/2023’), as.Date(‘1/11/2023’), as.Date(‘1/1/2023’))

rrt <- c(‘HD’, ‘HD’, ‘none’, ‘none’, ‘none’, ‘none’, ‘RRT’, ‘RRT’, ‘none’, ‘none’, ‘HD’)

death <- c(as.Date(‘12/30/2023’), as.Date(‘12/30/2023’), as.Date(‘12/30/2023’), as.Date(‘12/30/2023’), as.Date(‘12/30/2023’), as.Date(‘1/25/2023’), as.Date(‘2/10/2023’), as.Date(‘2/10/2023’), as.Date(‘1/30/2023’), as.Date(‘1/30/2023’), as.Date(‘12/30/2023’))

df_abx <- data.frame(ID, abx, abx_start, abx_stop, cx_final, rrt, death)
```

This is the solution I’d like to achieve:

| ID | abx | abx_start | abx_stop | cx_final | rrt | death. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | amp, ceft | 1/1/2023 | 1/30/2023 | 1/2/2023 | HD | 12/30/2023 |
| C2 | amp | 1/10/2023 | 2/14/2023 | 1/10/2023 | none | 12/30/2023 |
| C2 | ceft | 1/15/2023 | 2/14/2023 | 1/10/2023 | none | 12/30/2023 |
| C2 | vanc | 1/1/2023 | 1/3/2023 | 1/3/2023 | none | 12/30/2023 |
| C3 | amp | 1/11/2023 | 1/24/2023 | 1/11/2023 | none | 1/25/2023 |
| C4 | amp, gent | 1/20/2023 | 2/10/2023 | 1/18/2023 | RRT | 2/10/2023 |
| C5 | amp | 1/12/2023 | 1/30/2023 | 1/11/2023 | none | 1/30/2023 |
| C5 | vanc | 1/15/2023 | 1/15/2023 | 1/11/2023 | none | 1/30/2023 |
| C6 | vanc | 1/1/2023 | 1/14/2023 | 1/1/2023 | HD | 12/30/2023 |

Is there a way to do this? I’ve tried a number of different combinations for summarise and coalesce but keep losing the additional data columns I want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier/better approach to this problem, but here is a potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

ID <- c('C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C4', 'C5', 'C5', 'C6')
abx <- c('amp', 'ceft', 'amp', 'ceft', 'vanc', 'amp', 'amp', 'gent', 'amp', 'vanc', 'vanc')
abx_start <- c(mdy('1/1/2023'), mdy('1/3/2023'), mdy('1/10/2023'), mdy('1/15/2023'), mdy('1/1/2023'), mdy('1/11/2023'), mdy('1/20/2023'), mdy('1/21/2023'), mdy('1/12/2023'), mdy('1/15/2023'), mdy('1/1/2023'))
abx_stop <- c(mdy('1/30/2023'), mdy('1/29/2023'), mdy('2/14/2023'), mdy('2/14/2023'),mdy('1/3/2023'), mdy('1/24/2023'), mdy('2/10/2023'), mdy('2/08/2023'), mdy('1/30/2023'), mdy('1/15/2023'), mdy('1/14/2023'))
cx_final <- c(mdy('1/2/2023'), mdy('1/2/2023'), mdy('1/10/2023'), mdy('1/10/2023'), mdy('1/3/2023'), mdy('1/11/2023'), mdy('1/18/2023'), mdy('1/18/2023'), mdy('1/11/2023'), mdy('1/11/2023'), mdy('1/1/2023'))
rrt <- c('HD', 'HD', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'RRT', 'RRT', 'none', 'none', 'HD')
death <- c(mdy('12/30/2023'), mdy('12/30/2023'), mdy('12/30/2023'), mdy('12/30/2023'), mdy('12/30/2023'), mdy('1/25/2023'), mdy('2/10/2023'), mdy('2/10/2023'), mdy('1/30/2023'), mdy('1/30/2023'), mdy('12/30/2023'))
df_abx <- data.frame(ID, abx, abx_start, abx_stop, cx_final, rrt, death)

output <- df_abx %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(ID, abx_start) %>%
  mutate(count = 1) %>%
  mutate(subgroup = ifelse(
    abx_start < lag(abx_start, default = first(abx_start)) + 3,
    count,
    cumsum(count)
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(subgroup, .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(ID, abx = paste0(abx, collapse = ","),
            abx_start, abx_stop, cx_final, rrt, death) %>%
  group_by(abx, .add = TRUE) %>%
  filter(duplicated(abx)|n() == 1) %>%
  arrange(ID, abx) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-subgroup)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'ID', 'subgroup'. You can override using
#> the `.groups` argument.
output
#> # A tibble: 9 × 7
#>   ID    abx      abx_start  abx_stop   cx_final   rrt   death     
#>   <chr> <chr>    <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr> <date>    
#> 1 C1    amp,ceft 2023-01-03 2023-01-29 2023-01-02 HD    2023-12-30
#> 2 C2    amp      2023-01-10 2023-02-14 2023-01-10 none  2023-12-30
#> 3 C2    ceft     2023-01-15 2023-02-14 2023-01-10 none  2023-12-30
#> 4 C2    vanc     2023-01-01 2023-01-03 2023-01-03 none  2023-12-30
#> 5 C3    amp      2023-01-11 2023-01-24 2023-01-11 none  2023-01-25
#> 6 C4    amp,gent 2023-01-21 2023-02-08 2023-01-18 RRT   2023-02-10
#> 7 C5    amp      2023-01-12 2023-01-30 2023-01-11 none  2023-01-30
#> 8 C5    vanc     2023-01-15 2023-01-15 2023-01-11 none  2023-01-30
#> 9 C6    vanc     2023-01-01 2023-01-14 2023-01-01 HD    2023-12-30
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hm. This seems to get me part of the way there (the sub group aspect is really helpful), but before it finishes running I get the following error: "Warning: Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0. Please use `reframe()` instead."

Comment: Interesting - I've never seen that warning before - do you still get the correct answer? It says "Warning", not "Error", so I assume the function runs to completion; if you can create a reproducible example that returns that warning I would be happy to look into it further